# Services not starting after upgrade 18.04 -> 20.04

Tags: python, systemd, python3, unattended-upgrades

need some help.

After upgrading the following services wont start again:

```
  UNIT                        LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION                           
● networkd-dispatcher.service loaded failed failed Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd
● unattended-upgrades.service loaded failed failed Unattended Upgrades Shutdown          

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

2 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
```

journalctl shows the following:

```
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Oct 14 03:28:34 homie sudo[31802]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Oct 14 03:28:34 homie unattended-upgrade-shutdown[31805]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Oct 14 03:28:34 homie unattended-upgrade-shutdown[31805]:   File "/usr/share/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrade-shutdown", line 28, in <module>
Oct 14 03:28:34 homie unattended-upgrade-shutdown[31805]:     import dbus
Oct 14 03:28:34 homie unattended-upgrade-shutdown[31805]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
Oct 14 03:28:34 homie unattended-upgrade-shutdown[31805]:     import dbus.types as types
Oct 14 03:28:34 homie unattended-upgrade-shutdown[31805]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/types.py", line 6, in <module>
Oct 14 03:28:34 homie unattended-upgrade-shutdown[31805]:     from _dbus_bindings import (
Oct 14 03:28:34 homie unattended-upgrade-shutdown[31805]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_dbus_bindings'
Oct 14 03:28:34 homie systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

```
Oct 14 03:49:34 homie sudo[4641]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by ak(uid=0)
Oct 14 03:49:35 homie systemd[1]: networkd-dispatcher.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 14 03:49:35 homie networkd-dispatcher[4644]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Oct 14 03:49:35 homie networkd-dispatcher[4644]:   File "/usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher", line 23, in <module>
Oct 14 03:49:35 homie networkd-dispatcher[4644]:     from gi.repository import GLib as glib
Oct 14 03:49:35 homie networkd-dispatcher[4644]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
Oct 14 03:49:35 homie networkd-dispatcher[4644]:     from . import _gi
Oct 14 03:49:35 homie networkd-dispatcher[4644]: ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from partially initialized module 'gi' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)
Oct 14 03:49:35 homie sudo[4641]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Oct 14 03:49:35 homie systemd[1]: networkd-dispatcher.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

So it obviously has to do with pyhton. But I can't find anything of help?
Any ideas?

Thanks
Alex